# Unit Testing with ForEach

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing

Assuming:
"personList" is a list of Person objects

"agent" is an object that can provide activity about Shop objects (a property of Person)

"GetShopActivity" returns a list of shopping activity objects for a Person

I have this line in a test project:

```
personList.ForEach(p => new List<Person>(p.Shops)
    .ForEach(t=> Assert.IsNotNull(agent.GetShopActivity(t, startDate, endDate))));
```

How can I make it better?

Comment: Make it more readable.

Comment: Define what you mean by better.  What's wrong with it currently?  Although I echo @stuartd, it could easily be made more readable.

Comment: Put each nested/subsequent method call on a new line.

Comment: Why use `ForEach` at all, IMHO `foreach` would be more readable.  You could also avoid creating that intermediate list.

Comment: Use a real `foreach`.  Don't abuse lists just do you can stuff all this on one line.

Comment: I feel like you should read this blog post by Eric Lippert [foreach vs ForEach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Comment: Possibly better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Oh, there's a codereview? Nice.

Comment: Protip: you might want to include the whole test method if you're going to post this on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a lot you could do, but the first thing to do would be to make it more readable. Perhaps something like this:

```
var nullActivities = 
  from p in partnerList
  from t in p.Tenants
  let activity = agent.GetShopActivity(t, startDate, endDate)
  where activity == null
  select activity;

Assert.Empty(nullActivities);
```

**Moreover:**

you may want to think about

- [a test should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/02/why-trust-tests/) (i.e. it should have a [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of 1).
- it should be immediately evident to a person reading the test what scenario and behaviour is being tested (in case the values of `startDate` and `endDate` are significant it might be beneficial to give them less generic names).
- prefer having only a single assertion as that makes it easy to know where the test failed when it fails.

Comment: You could make that one query by changing the `select` in the first one to `let a =` and just using the `where` and `select` from the second one.

Comment: Thanks, @Rune, doing some reading on Cyclomatic Complexity, guidance indicates, your should have the number of tests for a method being equal to the Cyclomatic Complexity of the method. (http://www.rkcole.com/articles/other/CodeMetrics-CCN.html)

Comment: Also, this may be a bit much, but how can a unit test itself have a Cyclomatic Complexity of less than 2? Isn't an assertion a conditional?